# Why is augmented assignment of a tuple with iterable unpacking invalid syntax?

Tags: python-3.x

This is OK:

```py
a = 1, 2, 3
b = *a,
```

But this is invalid syntax:

```py
b += *a,
```

This is OK:

```py
b += (*a,)
```

**Update**

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html):

assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (**starred_expression** | yield_expression)

augmented_assignment_stmt ::=  augtarget augop (**expression_list** | yield_expression)

So here is a difference in the specifications of an assignment and an augmented assignment - the latter has **expression_list** instead of **starred_expression**.

Still, it would be nice if someone could explain the reason in plain language. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, that comes from [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), "(expressions...)" have the highest one. Not sure about the case, when tuple is defined implicitly.
Take look at this:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> b = (1, 2, 3)
>>> b = b + *a,
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    b = b + *a,
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> b = b + (*a,)
>>> b
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: += is not an operator.

Comment: But "(expressions...)" is :)
In the first case you have syntax error, but in the second case you are concatenating tuples (explanation is provided above).

Comment: This is different.  In 'b + *a,'  '+'  is an operator, so you have an invalid expression 'b + *a' followed by a comma. OTOH, 'b += *a,' is not much different from 'b = *a,' - there is a tuple on the right hand side of an assignment.

Comment: The only fault here is that you start with "probably" :) +1

Comment: MadPhysicist, that's just to be soft, thank you.
@Gene a += 1 is like a = a + 1, just try to simplify the code (= in the second case (*a,) is a tuple as "(...)" operation is performed with the highest priority, in the first case you are trying to perform weird operation " + *a, ", that causes error.

Comment: 'a += 4, 5' is not the same as 'a = a + 4, 5'.

Comment: @Gene Please take a look at [augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) "a[i] += f(x) first looks-up a[i], then it evaluates f(x) and performs the addition". As was previously described, in the first case there is a try to perform weird action **+ *a,** And in second case concatenating tuples is fine. Good like to you :)

Comment: In this case f(x) is '*a,' which should evaluate to tuple. Good luck to you too.

Comment: Yes. Thanks to you, now I definitely know, how the augment assignments work. This is a pretty cool task, by the way :)